# Fitting 3D data to a line in python

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I want to fit a 3D plot to a line in python. A minimal example is the following:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as img
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-10,10,0.01)
y = np.arange(-1,1,0.01)
[X,Y] = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = exp(-(X-8*Y+2)**2/10)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im  = img.NonUniformImage(ax, interpolation='bilinear')
im.set_data(x,y,z)
ax.images.append(im)
ax.set_xlim(-10,10)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

The figure generated is:
[image: example data for fitting]

I want to use a line to fit such data, with a weight such that the dark red data has most weight while the dark blue data has least weight. Essentially, I want to find that the curve is x-8y+2=0.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: To fit curves you can use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit()`(non-linear) or `numpy.polyfit()` (polynomial fit), among other methods.